# Open dictionary from .txt file en add/update new dict items and write updated dict to .txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to open a dictionary from .txt-file en add/update new dict items and write updated dict to .txt-file

When I run program and give a date and hours I get this error:

> -ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is         required.

My code:

```
old_dates_hours = {}
dates_hours = {}

def date():
    date = input('\nEnter a date: ')
    while True:
        try:
            hours = float(input('Enter hours: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('That was not a number!')
            continue
        else:
            break
    dates_hours[date.capitalize()] = hours
    answer = ask_yes_no("\nWant to enter more dates?, Enter 'y' of 'n': ")

    return dates_hours

def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Ask a yes or no question."""
    response = None
    while response not in ('y', 'n'):
        response = input(question).lower()
        if response == 'y':
            date()
        else:
            print('\nYou dont have more hours to fill in ')

    return response


def open_and_read_file():
    hours_file = open('HOURS.txt', 'r+')
    old_dates_hours = hours_file.readline()
    hours_file.close()

    return old_dates_hours


def write_to_file():
    hours_file = open('HOURS.txt', 'w')
    hours_file.write(str(dates_hours))
    hours_file.close()


dates_hours = date()
print('\nNew entered hours: ', dates_hours)
old_dates_hours = open_and_read_file()
print('\nOld hours: ', old_dates_hours)
print('\nThis are the recently given hours: ', dates_hours)
dates_hours.update(old_dates_hours)
print('This are the total saved hours: ', dates_hours)
write_ = write_to_file()
```

I have tested the "dates_hours.update(old_dates_hours)" function in code below:
This works for me but I can't get it working in code above.

```
old_dates_hours = {'Za': 4, 'Zo': 6}
dates_hours = {'Ma': 13, 'Di': 9, 'Wo': 9, 'Vr': 5}

dates_hours.update(old_dates_hours)
print(dates_hours)

def write_to_file():
    uren_file = open('HOURS3.txt', 'w')
    uren_file.write(str(dates_hours))
    uren_file.close()

write_ = write_to_file()
```

Comment: You should also **check the Python documentation pages for help** - there's lots of useful explanations there, descriptions of features and a tutorial section. A good reference place too. "update([other]): Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm)

> The method update() adds dictionary dict2's key-values pairs in to
>   dict.

Your `open_and_read_file()` function returns a list, not a dictionary. Because [readlines()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm) returns a list. You need to make a dictionary from your "HOURS.txt", then try to update.

**EDIT:**

If your txt content is something like `{'Mo':4, 'Vr':6, 'So':5}`, you can use this:

```
import ast

# rest of the code

def open_and_read_file():
    hours_file = open('HOURS.txt', 'r+')
    old_dates_hours = ast.literal_eval(hours_file.read())
    hours_file.close()

    return old_dates_hours
```

Comment: On top of my program I define "old_dates_hours = {}" so If the HOURS.txt file contains nothing, the program know's that the old_dates_hours must be an dictionary.                                                        When my HOURS.txt file contains already a dictionary with a number of dates and hours, like---> {'Mo':4, 'Vr':6, 'So':5} the program returns a dictionary, I check it with a print statement(print(old_dates_hours) in the "def open_and_read_file():" function.                                                   So I don't understand why readline() returns a list?

Comment: `readlines()` returns the list of the lines. If your txt file has single line which is `{'Mo':4, 'Vr':6, 'So':5}`, `readlines()` returns a list with one item. The list is `[{'Mo':4, 'Vr':6, 'So':5}]`. I added a suggestion to my answer.